# how to fit both text and image in a row using 2 col-md-6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, text

```css
<style>
    .backgroundcolor1 {
        background-color: #567892;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="row" align="center">
        <div class="col-md-12 backgroundcolor1">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 ">
                    <br>
                    <img src="assets/images/SPA/Icons/facials.png" class="icons" alt=""><br>
                    <h3>FACIALS</h3>
                    <p align="justify">Have you ever treated to a facial?<br> Facial treatments feel good, offering soothing relaxation, according to Day Spas. Facial massage treatments increase circulation and the flow of blood, and they include a variety of cremes,
                        aromatherapy and oils that moisturize the skin, smell good, and relieve stress as well as encourage peace of mind and contentment</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 textbox">

                <img src="assets/images/SPA/facial.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;opacity:0.9;padding:0;margin:0; " alt="">
                <figcaption><br><br><br>
                    <h3>Facials</h3>
                </figcaption>
                [enter image description here][1]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am getting proper image fitting to text.. after i start resizing my image start reducing and there will be gap like the below image. i don't want it to happen for all the devices. my entire site is in this manner only. i don't want that extra background showing at the right side of the image.can anybody help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: use .img-responsive class to fit the image into a div

Comment: I will check with this and see.. hope this works..

Comment: no its not working..

Comment: Use background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create row inside col-md-6 and define column that you want like

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 textbox">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
          <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
          <p>Text goes here.....</p>
          <p>ddescription goes here</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

you can print text first and image in second and change col length with your need. I hope this is what you need if not please try to clarify your question.

Comment: you are using col inside col please add row then col i.e. make row after backgroundcolor1 class

Comment: for using col in proper way you should use it inside row

Comment: if you have only one col you can use it inside col but if you have more than one col you should use it inside row.

Comment: if your problem is solved please accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```css
.backgroundcolor1 {
        background-color: #567892;
    }
 
    .back_imag{position:absolute !important; background:url(http://via.placeholder.com/500x400) no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center center; left:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row" align="center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 backgroundcolor1">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 ">
                    <br>
                    <img src="assets/images/SPA/Icons/facials.png" class="icons" alt=""><br>
                    <h3>FACIALS</h3>
                    <p align="justify">Have you ever treated to a facial?<br> Facial treatments feel good, offering soothing relaxation, according to Day Spas. Facial massage treatments increase circulation and the flow of blood, and they include a variety of cremes,
                        aromatherapy and oils that moisturize the skin, smell good, and relieve stress as well as encourage peace of mind and contentment</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 textbox back_imag col-xs-offset-6">

                <img src="" class="" alt="">
                <figcaption><br><br><br>
                    <h3>Facials</h3>
                </figcaption>
                [enter image description here][1]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```